# SSH session limit

Tags: ssh

How can I increase the ssh connection on my freeBSD jump server. I am using pssh to push configs to multiple servers by tuneling through my jump server. As of now I can only push configs to 9 servers at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Set `MaxSessions` to a higher value (default: 10) in [sshd_config(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and restart `sshd`.

You will probably want to adjust `MaxStartups` as well. The man page explains everything.